What do do with my Digital Juice Sound FX Library (v1-4)?
I have the entire Digital Juice Sound FX Library and I work on a MAC, which means the old Juicer software that managed the sound effects library does not work.
I would like to rip the sounds off the disks and put them on my hard drive. But I need metadata for those sounds...  LiquidBlasted, on this forum, had spreadsheets as of 2014, but the link is broken. And for some reason, I can't reachout directly on this platform, or comment on the post that talked about those spreadsheets.
I'm wondering if anyone can help me? I invested the money. I'd like to continue using the sound fx library. Thank you.

I have a soft spot for digital archeology of vintage Mac sounds.
I wonder if SoundMiner can help? They mention Digital Juice: https://info.soundminer.com/docs/import-text
It's been years, but some of the people here might have more leads? https://www.dvxuser.com/threads/i-beat-the-juicer.321611/
And if you use Parallels or another virtualizer, you might reach out and try this? http://s.co.tt/2015/07/08/digital-juice-sound-effects-library-file-renamer/
All the best recovering the metadata!

TORLEY, thank you very much. I will take a look at all these options you've laid out.
